# ROS Answers SE migration: tum_ardrone

Tags: ros, tum-ardrone

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I compile tum_ardrone in Linux Mint 14 on my ASUS 64b laptop, after applying all the fixes specified in --answers.ros.org/question/89181/rosmake-tum_ardrone/--,
drone_autopilot & drone_gui compile sucessfully but drone_stateestimation does not. I can sucessfully fly my drone and control it with my keypad using drone_gui. I am using ROS groovy.

The error messages from the unsucessful "rosmake tum_ardrone" are as follows:

### [ rosmake ] Last 40 lines
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/home/zeus/catkin_ws/devel/tum_ardrone/thirdparty/TooN/include/TooN/internal/vbase.hh:72:12:   required from ‘TooN::Internal::VBase::VLayout<Size, Precision>::VLayout() [with int Size = 4; Precision = float]’
/home/zeus/catkin_ws/devel/tum_ardrone/thirdparty/TooN/include/TooN/internal/vector.hh:143:17:   required from ‘TooN::Vector<Size, Precision, Base>::Vector() [with int Size = 4; Precision = float; Base = TooN::Internal::VBase]’
/home/zeus/catkin_ws/devel/tum_ardrone/thirdparty/TooN/include/TooN/internal/make_vector.hh:49:24:   required from ‘TooN::Vector<4, Precision> TooN::makeVector(const Precision&, const Precision&, const Precision&, const Precision&) [with Precision = float]’
/home/zeus/catkin_ws/devel/tum_ardrone/src/autopilot/DroneController.cpp:58:88:   required from here
/home/zeus/catkin_ws/devel/tum_ardrone/thirdparty/TooN/include/TooN/internal/allocator.hh:60:3: warning: ‘debug_initialize’ was not declared in this scope, and no declarations were found by argument-dependent lookup at the point of instantiation [-fpermissive]
In file included from /home/zeus/catkin_ws/devel/tum_ardrone/thirdparty/TooN/include/TooN/TooN.h:255:0,
from /home/zeus/catkin_ws/devel/tum_ardrone/thirdparty/TooN/include/TooN/so3.h:33,
from /home/zeus/catkin_ws/devel/tum_ardrone/thirdparty/TooN/include/TooN/se3.h:33,
from /home/zeus/catkin_ws/devel/tum_ardrone/src/autopilot/DroneController.h:27,
from /home/zeus/catkin_ws/devel/tum_ardrone/src/autopilot/DroneController.cpp:23:
/home/zeus/catkin_ws/devel/tum_ardrone/thirdparty/TooN/include/TooN/internal/debug.hh:104:33: note: ‘template void TooN::Internal::debug_initialize(P*, int)’ declared here, later in the translation unit
In file included from /home/zeus/catkin_ws/devel/tum_ardrone/thirdparty/TooN/include/TooN/TooN.h:250:0,
from /home/zeus/catkin_ws/devel/tum_ardrone/thirdparty/TooN/include/TooN/so3.h:33,
from /home/zeus/catkin_ws/devel/tum_ardrone/thirdparty/TooN/include/TooN/se3.h:33,
from /home/zeus/catkin_ws/devel/tum_ardrone/src/autopilot/DroneController.h:27,
from /home/zeus/catkin_ws/devel/tum_ardrone/src/autopilot/DroneController.cpp:23:
/home/zeus/catkin_ws/devel/tum_ardrone/thirdparty/TooN/include/TooN/internal/allocator.hh: In instantiation of ‘TooN::Internal::StackOrHeap<Size, Precision, false>::StackOrHeap() [with int Size = 4; Precision = int]’:
/home/zeus/catkin_ws/devel/tum_ardrone/thirdparty/TooN/include/TooN/internal/allocator.hh:107:43:   required from ‘TooN::Internal::VectorAlloc<Size, Precision>::VectorAlloc() [with int Size = 4; Precision = int]’
/home/zeus/catkin_ws/devel/tum_ardrone/thirdparty/TooN/include/TooN/internal/vbase.hh:96:16:   required from ‘TooN::Internal::GenericVBase<Size, Precision, Stride, Mem>::GenericVBase() [with int Size = 4; Precision = int; int Stride = 1; Mem = TooN::Internal::VectorAlloc<4, int>]’
/home/zeus/catkin_ws/devel/tum_ardrone/thirdparty/TooN/include/TooN/internal/vbase.hh:72:12:   required from ‘TooN::Internal::VBase::VLayout<Size, Precision>::VLayout() [with int Size = 4; Precision = int]’
/home/zeus/catkin_ws/devel/tum_ardrone/thirdparty/TooN/include/TooN/internal/vector.hh:143:17:   required from ‘TooN::Vector<Size, Precision, Base>::Vector() [with int Size = 4; Precision = int; Base = TooN::Internal::VBase]’
/home/zeus/catkin_ws/devel/tum_ardrone/thirdparty/TooN/include/TooN/internal/make_vector.hh:49:24:   required from ‘TooN::Vector<4, Precision> TooN::makeVector(const Precision&, const Precision&, const Precision&, const Precision&) [with Precision = int]’
/home/zeus/catkin_ws/devel/tum_ardrone/src/autopilot/DroneController.cpp:95:46:   required from here
/home/zeus/catkin_ws/devel/tum_ardrone/thirdparty/TooN/include/TooN/internal/allocator.hh:60:3: warning: ‘debug_initialize’ was not declared in this scope, and no declarations were found by argument-dependent lookup at the point of instantiation [-fpermissive]
In file included from /home/zeus/catkin_ws/devel/tum_ardrone/thirdparty/TooN/include/TooN/TooN.h:255:0,
from /home/zeus/catkin_ws/devel/tum_ardrone/thirdparty/TooN/include/TooN/so3.h:33,
from /home/zeus/catkin_ws/devel/tum_ardrone/thirdparty/TooN/include/TooN/se3.h:33,
from /home/zeus/catkin_ws/devel/tum_ardrone/src/autopilot/DroneController.h:27,
from /home/zeus/catkin_ws/devel/tum_ardrone/src/autopilot/DroneController.cpp:23:
/home/zeus/catkin_ws/devel/tum_ardrone/thirdparty/TooN/include/TooN/internal/debug.hh:104:33: note: ‘template void TooN::Internal::debug_initialize(P*, int)’ declared here, later in the translation unit
make[4]: *** [CMakeFiles/drone_autopilot.dir/src/autopilot/main_autopilot.cpp.o] Error 1
make[4]: *** [CMakeFiles/drone_autopilot.dir/src/autopilot/DroneController.cpp.o] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/zeus/catkin_ws/devel/tum_ardrone/build' make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/drone_autopilot.dir/all] Error 2 make[3]: Leaving directory` /home/zeus/catkin_ws/devel/tum_ardrone/build'
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/zeus/catkin_ws/devel/tum_ardrone/build' make[1]: *** [all] Error 2 make[1]: Leaving directory` /home/zeus/catkin_ws/devel/tum_ardrone'

[ rosmake ] Output from build of package tum_ardrone written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/zeus/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20140112-170054/tum_ardrone/build_output.log
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< tum_ardrone [FAIL] [ 7.65 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package tum_ardrone.
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[ rosmake ] Results:
[ rosmake ] Built 49 packages with 1 failures.
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory
[ rosmake ] /home/zeus/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20140112-170054

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/117176/tum_ardrone/) by [rosdrone99](https://answers.ros.org/users/10751/rosdrone99/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-01-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you installed and compiled TooN on your computer?

Install TooN :  git clone git clone git://github.com/edrosten/TooN.git
This will create a TooN directory wherever you cloned it to. Navigate to the TooN directory and type :

./configure

make

make install

---

Originally posted by [lppier](https://answers.ros.org/users/11266/lppier/) with karma: 41 on 2014-01-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0